Firmware Updates for Dell XPS15 9500
I have an XPS15 9500 that is running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  I have kept the BIOS up-to-date (currently at 1.28.0) but at startup I am always informed that there are two out-of-date firmware packages:

Thunderbolt Controller 43.0 -> 60.0
WD19 Device 01.00.36.00 -> 01.00.36.01
The latter is for the WD19TB dock.  I have tried to install these many times without success.

The Dell support site proposes Windows installers for these firmware packages.  But I have never run Windows on this machine!  (It came with Windows 10 installed, but I immediately formatted the drive and installed Ubuntu.  That cuts me off from any Dell support!)
I plan to upgrade to 24.04 LTS as soon as it is available.  I would like to have all of the system firmware up-to-date, unless it is really unnecessary.
Any suggestions on how to proceed?  Thanks in advance ...
/added 26 may 2024 12:10 UTC/
I ran fwupdmgr :
$ fwupdmgr get-devices
XPS 15 9500
│
│ ...
│   
├─WD19TB:
│ │   Device ID:          570867f4ddda9915445da59bd85cd0e0e507270e
│ │   Summary:            High performance dock
│ │   Current version:    01.01.00.07
│ │   Vendor:             Dell Inc. (USB:0x413C)
│ │   Install Duration:   1 minute
│ │   GUID:               cd357cf1-40b2-5d87-b8df-bb2dd82774aa
│ │   Device Flags:       • Updatable
│ │                       • Supported on remote server
│ │                       • Device stages updates
│ │                       • Device can recover flash failures
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │                       • Signed Payload
│ │ 
│ │ ...
│     
│ ...
│     
├─Thunderbolt host controller:
│     Device ID:          f58c66bcd299fdb50f378d8682fabea77b4abd70
│     Summary:            Unmatched performance for high-speed I/O
│     Current version:    56.00
│     Vendor:             Dell (THUNDERBOLT:0x00D4, TBT:0x00D4)
│     GUIDs:              86690f6b-9493-5d1d-83f9-06d10be118a5
│                         361351ad-1a46-5a42-b7fe-13c9d8a7fc40
│                         daeedfff-3bd8-5c15-9586-6bfe466b076a
│                         0257530f-0fd5-5f43-a478-465a9a10fefe
│     Device Flags:       • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • System requires external power source
│                         • Device stages updates
│                         • Signed Payload
│   
│ ...
________________________________________________

Devices that have been updated successfully:

...
 • WD19TB (01.01.00.05 → 01.01.00.07)
...
 • Thunderbolt controller in Dell dock (43.00 → 60.00)

Uploading firmware reports helps hardware vendors to quickly identify failing and successful updates on real devices.
Upload report now? (Requires internet connection) [Y|n]:

Then :
$ sudo fwupdmgr update
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • DELL097D:00 04F3:311C
 • Integrated Webcam HD
 • Thunderbolt host controller
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI dbx
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Package level of Dell dock
 • RTS5413 in Dell dock
 • RTS5487 in Dell dock
 • VMM5331 in Dell dock
 • WD19TB
 • KXG60PNV2T04 NVMe KIOXIA 2048GB
 • System Firmware

I then did a cold boot, and still the system reports:


Find out how the update is done: generally you need the firmware on a fat32 formatted cd/dvd/stick and install it from bios itself.  You could always do that from Linux."unless it is really unnecessary." when it come to BIOS: you should make sure the update fixes a bug you are affected by Otherwise you should leave it. And if the system is a production system, where you have not got a replacement ready,  I would never. Only on system you are not afraid to burn.

Hi Rinzwind -- Thanks.  The problem would be getting the firmware update from Dell without the Windows wrapper.  Probably best to just leave well enough alone and ignore the constant messages telling me to update the WD19 and Thunderbolt firmware!  Still, it would be nice have it fully up-to-date before I install 24.04 LTS.
